# TypeORM add a count for foreign key field in querybuilder

Tags: mysql, typeorm

My table setup is as follows

### Shortlist

| id (primary key) | property_id(foreign key) | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2 |
| 2 | 101 | 2 |
| 3 | 103 | 4 |
| 4 | 100 | 1 |
| 5 | 100 | 3 |
| 6 | 101 | 1 |

### Property

| id (primary key) | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 4 |

I then have the following query builder

```
const qb = ShortlistRepository.createQueryBuilder('s').distinct();

qb.innerJoinAndMapOne('s.property', Property, 'p', 's.`property_id` = p.`id`');
qb.where('s.`user_id` = :userId', { userId });
qb.groupBy('s.`property_id`');
qb.limit(12);

const shortlist = await qb.getMany();
```

I want to add a count field alias as `shortlistCount` that returns the total number of times each `property_id` field appears in the `shortlist` table. (or `id` field in the `property` table, whichever is easier in this context)

For example, the `property_id` of `100` appears `3` times in the shortlist table.

So the response should be something like if searching when `userId` is `2`

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    property_id: 100,
    user_id: 2,
    shortlistCount: 3,
    property: {
      id: 100,
      account_id: 1
      // can also add shortlistCount here if easier?
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    property_id: 101,
    user_id: 2,
    shortlistCount: 2,
    property: {
      id: 101,
      account_id: 2
      // can also add shortlistCount here if easier?
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by using a correlated subquery.

```
const qb = ShortlistRepository.createQueryBuilder('s').distinct();
qb.addSelect('(select Count(*) from shortlist s2 where s2.property_id = s.property_id)', `shortlistCount`);
qb.innerJoinAndMapOne('s.property', Property, 'p', 's.`property_id` = p.`id`');
qb.where('s.`user_id` = :userId', { userId });
qb.groupBy('s.`property_id`');
qb.limit(12);

const shortlist = await qb.getMany();
```